# Why is the short display name for Asia/Manila timezone PT in java?

Tags: java

```
jshell> import java.time.*;

jshell> import java.time.format.*;

jshell> ZoneId.of("Asia/Manila").getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.getDefault())
$1 ==> "PT"
```

From wikipedia:
Philippine Standard Time (PST or PhST), also known as Philippine Time (PHT), is the official name for the time zone used in the Philippines.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philippine_Standard_Time

Shouldn't it be PST instead of PT?

Comment: and you think the SO community decides on this?

Comment: No, `PHT`, `PST`, are *not* [official time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Real time zone names are `Continent/Region`. Ex: `Asia/Manila`, `Pacific/Auckland`, `Africa/Casablanca`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that it doesn't know the instant at which you want to know the time zone name. Exactly the same thing happens for America/Los_Angeles:

```
jshell> ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles").getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.getDefault())
$4 ==> "PT"
```

Try formatting an `ZonedDateTime` to just include the short zone name, you'll find it uses PST or PDT for Philippines Standard Time and Philippines Daylight Time respectively.

```
jshell> DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("z").format(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Manila")))
$8 ==> "PST"
```

---

As to why it does this: depends on which version of Java you are using, but it is because [something like this code](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/e7f7be79ba52/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/util/resources/TimeZoneNames.java#l680) is used to specify timezone names:

```
            {"Asia/Manila", new String[] {"Philippines Standard Time", "PST",
                                          "Philippines Daylight Time", "PDT",
                                          "Philippines Time", "PT"}},
```

It's not just the Philippines that has a non-standard "default" name: amongst many others, as a Brit, I have *never* heard the term ["British Time"](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/e7f7be79ba52/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/util/resources/TimeZoneNames.java#l149) before, or seen the abbreviation "BT" used in this way.

```
        String GMTBST[] = new String[] {"Greenwich Mean Time", "GMT",
                                        "British Summer Time", "BST",
                                        "British Time", "BT"};
```

```
jshell> ZoneId.of("Europe/London").getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.getDefault())
$10 ==> "BT"
```

Comment: And ... the corollary is that if you think PT should be PHT or something else, submit an issue to the Java Bug Tracker.  Provide definitive evidence that your proposed change to the short id is correct; i.e. cite specific authoritative sources.  (Wikipedia is not authoritative.)

Answer (score 0):

PST is the abbrevation for the Pacific Standart Time, so that's taken. It's like you've written in your question, PHT is the normal abbrevation for the Philippine Standart Time.

As for the "why PT":

That's just what they choose for Java.

Comment: "so that's taken" being "taken" isn't a thing - 3-letter abbreviations are discouraged precisely because they are ambiguous. Consider CST (China Standard Time, Central Standard Time) and IST (India Standard Time, Irish Standard Time, Israel Standard Time) etc.

Comment: As correctly [commented by Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70605148/why-is-the-short-display-name-for-asia-manila-timezone-pt-in-java/70605504#comment124812458_70605278), saying `PST` is "taken" is nonsensical. There is **no official registry** of these 2-4 letter pseudo-zones such as `PT`, `PST`, and `PHT`. They are invented locally, without regard for uniqueness, not standardized. And so several collisions have resulted. Avoid these 2-4 letter codes in your data storage, data exchange, serialization, and business logic. Use only for localization in presentation to the user.

Comment: I have to clarify what I meant:
With "taken" I didn't mean that it's the standard for everything. It's the standard for Java.